# SPServices Sum returned values

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, spservices

I'm using SPServices to query a SharePoint 2010 list, a can get only the values that I want but when I try to sum all of the it only show "as a string"

[image: alert of sum calculation]

Here is the code that i use:

```
var TotalAmount = 0.00;

$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: {list guid},
    viewName: {view guid},
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='AP' /><FieldRef Name='Amount' /></ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='AP' /><Value Type='Text'>"+areaValue+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status){
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
                var liHtml=$(this).attr("ows_Title");
                var app =$(this).attr("ows_AP");
                Amount = $(this).attr("ows_Amount");


                TotalAmount = TotalAmount + montante;


            });     
        }
});
  alert(TotalAmount);
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string values to numbers in JavaScript by using the `Number()` function.

```
Amount = $(this).attr("ows_Amount");
TotalAmount = TotalAmount + Number(Amount);
```

Note that you can also use a common shorthand of enclosing your variable in parentheses and preceding it with a plus sign (`+`) which instructs JavaScript to attempt to parse the variable as a number.

```
Amount = +( $(this).attr("ows_Amount") );
TotalAmount = TotalAmount + Amount;
```